# Print image in actual size

Tags: 18.04, printing, ubuntu-mate, gimp, kolourpaint

I want to print an image in it's actual size.

It is from a print screen from the internet.

Is there a way to print actual size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the image is a scan[1], there is no "actual" size, there is at best an intended print size. Your image has a size in pixels, and its print size depends on the ratio of pixels per unit of length, usually expressed as pixels per inch or PPI[2]. This ratio is called the print definition, and it kept as image metadata. In Gimp you can set it in `Image>Print size`, but keep in mind that a low print definition corresponds to low image quality, if there is text you should use at least 150PPI.

If by "actual size" you mean the size on your screen, then it's not the actual size but Gimp using the print definition of your screen (usually around 100-120PPI, unless you have a high def display) because Gimp displays the image "dot-for-dot" (one pixel of the image is mapped to exactly on pixel of the display). To make the image on your screen the same physical size as in print:

1. make sure Gimp has a good estimate of your screen definition: `Edit>Preferences>Display>Monitor resolution`
2. tell Gimp to not use "dot-for-dot": uncheck `View>Dot for dot`

Some more warnings:

- the default print definition is usually 72PPI (perhaps because it was the display definition of most CRT displays).
- The printer usually requires a print definition higher than your display, so unless you check the above the printed image will likely look smaller that the one on the screen.

[1] if the image is a scan, the scanner software has set the proper print definition in the image metadata.

[2] dots per inch, or DPI, is also used but this is misleading since inkjet printers use several dots of color to make a single color pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with [banana.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIynr.png)

Using `lp`, assuming `imageMagick` installed

list your printer options with

`terminal-where-image-is$ lpstat -p -d`

**set printer** with

`terminal-where-image-is$ lpoptions -d printer_name`

**set PPI (pixels per inch)** equal to the actual image property PPI

`terminal-where-image-is$ ppi=$(identify -format "%x" banana.png)`

now **to print as actual size** (from PPI setting)

`terminal-where-image-is$ lp -o ppi=$ppi banana.png`